# Optimization tips for fully automated, time-parallelized plotting of data from N-dimensional datasets

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, matplotlib-basemap, python-xarray

**Task**: produce plots (usually a combination of filled/non-filled contours) of some variables contained in dataset produced by numerical weather prediction models. This needs to be automated as new data are downloaded every 6 hours (approximately) and new plots are produced and uploaded to a FTP to be visualised ASAP.

**My solution and my problem**: the driver script which takes care of downloading and preparing the files is written in `bash` for speed reason. Since on the server the data is splitted in individual files containing one time instant and one level this phase is parallelized using (gnu) `parallel`. This phase is pretty fast and optimized. However, the next phase, which involves plotting of the data using `python` and mainly `matplotlib.pyplot` is still the longest one and requires a lot of memory.

**Anatomy of a plotting script**: I have 2 sections, a `main` function where all the pre-processing on the input files is done only once to use as little memory/computation as possible and a `plot_files` function which only plots the data.

```py
import xarray as xr 
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def main():
    file = glob(input_file)
    dset = xr.open_dataset(file[0])

    # Do some pre-processing and get the variables/coordinates
    # from the file
    var = dset.var
```

Next the `main` function spans multiple instances of the plotting function using `multiprocessing`. Here the figure instance of `matplotlib`, together with the `basemap` projection, are created so that it is only done once: the plotting function will take care of appending elements to the plot and remove them at every time step for the next iteration

```py
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax  = plt.gca()
    m, x, y = get_projection(lon2d, lat2d, projection)

    # All the arguments that need to be passed to the plotting function
    args = dict(m=m, x=x, y=y, ax=ax,
                  var=var, time=time, projection=projection)

    # Parallelize the plotting by dividing into chunks and processes 
    dates = chunks(time, chunks_size)
    plot_files_param = partial(plot_files, **args)
    p = Pool(processes)
    p.map(plot_files_param, dates)
```

Parallelising over time felt natural as you have to produce the same plot over many timestep but the data is already there to be used!

The plotting function does as little as possible: take the variable, makes the plot by overlying different levels (when required) and delete the elements when the figure has been exported to prepare for the next timestep.

```py
def plot_files(dates, **args):
    for date in dates:
        # Find index in the original array to subset when plotting
        i = np.argmin(np.abs(date - args['time'])) 
        cs = args['ax'].contourf(args['x'], args['y'], args['var'][i])

        plt.savefig(filename, **options_savefig)        

        remove_collections([cs])
```

`remove_collections` takes care of removing any element (could be contour lines, labels, annotation...).

Currently I have a script running for every different type of plot that I make while common functions are all imported from a `utils.py` module.

I'm sure this is not the smartest implementation of parallelized plotting. The drawbacks that I see right now are the usage of memory which could maybe reduced by passing to the `plot_files` function the array only at a certain timestep but I'm not sure one can parallelize with `multiprocessing` across a variable dimension.

Does anyone have some tip to improve my code? I tried to reduce the examples to the core but of course there are many more details. One of the projects involving this script can be seen here https://github.com/guidocioni/icon_forecasts

Comment: What backend are you using? If you anyway only save the figures without looking at them, using, e.g., 'Agg' may speed up your script as is.

Comment: Of course I'm using the `Agg` backend as I'm saving the figures in png as they are produced.